# Erro no angular-animate: angular.module(...).info is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

Eu estou tentando usar o angular animate, ms to tendo o erro no console só de importar o angular-animate.js

> Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info is not a function
>       at angular-animate.js:4139
>       at angular-animate.js:4155

Meu arquivo app.

```
var app = angular.module('main', ['ui.router','ngAnimate']);
```

Até então não chamei nhm função do animate por conta desse erro.

Comment: Testou se o js está com o path correto? Por exemplo `<script src="scripts/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>`, existe a pasta scripts/angular (no seu caso a sua pasta)? O arquivo está lá na pasta correta?

Comment: Está com o caminho correto sim amigo. Estranho é q qnd clico no arquivo do erro, ele me mostra essa linha do angular animate: .info({ angularVersion: '1.6.3' }). Eu baixei tanto o angular qnto o angular animate pelo bower. e meu angular tá na 1.6.2. Seria versionamento diferente a causa do erro :o ??

Comment: This is new functionality in 1.6.3, prior to that, 1.5.11 did not have `.info`. Either force bower not to pull down ngAnimate 1.6.3, or pull down angular 1.6.3. Apologies for this being in english, I found this via google, and was the only question about this.

Comment: Não entendi porque é um problema que "não pode ser reproduzido", mas enfim.. coloco a resposta aqui. O motivo é que todos os módulos do Angular devem ser da mesma versão. Ou seja, o seu `angular-animate` deveria ser da versão 1.6.2 também

Answer (score 0):

Tive um problema parecido com o angular touch.A causa disso é que o angular adicionou o método [module info](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/15225), que permite que desenvolvedores adicionem informações arbitrárias sobre seus módulos. Você provavelmente está utilizando uma versão do `NgAnimate` que se tornou incompatível com sua versão do angular por não conter este método.

Como dito pelo @Pureferret, o problema pode ser resolvido utilizando uma versão mais antiga do `NgAnimate`.

Answer (score 0):

Fala pessoal, eu havia esquecido de dar o bower init. Estava faltando o bower.json. Qnd executei, e criou, notei que não estava registrado a dependencia do angular no bower.json. Ao inseri-la, passou a funcionar. Obgd a todos!